# Updating nested Array data using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested-sets, insert-update

I have nested data:

```
Object
_id: "90fac6ab-b88e-42a1-8e91-80ee25951ec7"
  answers: Array[4]
    0: Object
      name: "myData"
      owned_by: "273b7291-df2b-494c-bd9b-64e71283447e"
      score: 0
```

I am trying to update, only a specific nested `answer` whose name I know. I would simply like to increment the `score` field, and I only know `name`. How does one accomplish this?

Thus far I have this:  `db.Question.update({_id: "90fac6ab-b88e-42a1-8e91-80ee25951ec7"}, "myData":{$inc: {score: 2}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to increment the score of each answer based on the name of the answerer (I assume that's what name is) as such:

```
db.Question.update({
    _id: "90fac6ab-b88e-42a1-8e91-80ee25951ec7", 
    answers.name : "myData"
}, {$inc: {"answers.$.score": 1}})
```

Should work. I use the positional operator here to reach into a suboducment to populate the `$`: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Comment: Dang! You just beat me to it (poor train wifi).

Comment: Is there any way to update the nested queried object using $set and passing an object only containing attributes to be updated? 
I mean something like this as second arg

{$set : {"answers.$" : {attr1:val1, attr2:val2}}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
db.Question.update({ _id: "90fac6ab-b88e-42a1-8e91-80ee25951ec7", "answers.name": "myData" }, 
                   { $inc: { "answers.$.score": 2} });
```